# What to store in XDG_DATA_HOME?

Tags: home, xdg

I'm reading up on the [XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html), but I'm having some trouble understanding what exactly the `$XDG_DATA_HOME` is for. The specification mentions the following:

> There is a single base directory relative to which user-specific data files should be written. This directory is defined by the environment variable `$XDG_DATA_HOME`.

But I'm not sure how to interpret *user-specific data files*. Is this intended for read only data data that supports an application, like graphics, sound files, fonts...? Or is this for data that the user creates using an application?

I'm asking this because I have two applications for which I don't know whether their data belongs in `XDG_DATA_HOME` or not?

- Task warrior creates a data file containing all your tasks (together with their metadata). These data files are not static, they change as you add/modify/remove tasks. They are, however, never edited manually, you always use the application to add/modify/remove tasks.
- I have a backup script that generates tarballs. These tarballs are obviously stored remotely, but I want to also store them locally for quick access in certain situations.

Comment: Are you asking from a app developer or a app user point of view ?

Comment: Does that matter? Because I'm a user of the task warrior app, but I'm a developer of my personal backup script.

Comment: XDG is usually only available if you have a graphical user environment based on GTK (e.g. Gnome, Mate, ...). Therefore I assume your backup script should not rely on the existence of XDG.

Comment: Perhaps not in that specific case, but the question is still relevant for cases where we can assume that XDG is present (or we can use the defaults if the values aren't set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the purpose of `XDG_DATA_HOME` is to store data created by applications *on behalf* of a specific user, but in a form that the user doesn’t care about directly. That is to say, files which the user wouldn’t expect to care about individually, or wish to copy as such to another system (or send to another user). These are files that are only ever accessed through an application of some kind, like your Task Warrior data file.

Note however that the specification does seem to allow usage akin to `/usr/share`, *i.e.* application data files that aren’t intrinsically specific to a given user, if a given user installs an application in their home directory. In such scenarios, binaries would go in `~/.local/bin`, and associated data in `XDG_DATA_HOME`.

Data which stores configuration should go in `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`. Another way to think of this is that if a user backs up and restores `XDG_DATA_HOME`, they should get all their data back, but not their settings; if they back up and restore `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, they should get their settings back.

Data which can be *re-created* should go in `XDG_CACHE_HOME`, and I would say that your tarballs fit in there.

(Considerations about whether the `$XDG` environment variables are set or not, which is usually tied to a desktop environment, aren’t all that relevant since the specification gives defaults to use in the absence of environment variables.)

Comment: So if I understand correctly, `XDG_DATA_HOME` can be used for both?

Comment: No: the Task Warrior data can go there, but the backup tarballs should go in `XDG_CACHE_HOME`.

Comment: `XDG_CACHE_HOME` is for non essential data, but what I don't want to lose the different backups (checkpoints) that were made.

Comment: You wrote that “[t]hese tarballs are obviously stored remotely”, so they aren’t essential data. Storing them in `XDG_CACHE_HOME` doesn’t mean that they’ll be deleted; it means that they can be retrieved from elsewhere (and therefore typically don’t need to be backed up).